# Map Value gets overwritten

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, map

I have a scheduled Apex job that queries a child object and ordered by the parent Id. Then I have a for loop that groups all the child objects w/ the same parent Id into a list and then cache them in a map using the parent Id as a key. Before cache into a map, the key-value pair was correct, but then after if's put into a map, the value gets overwritten. Below is the Apex job. Thanks for all your help!!

```
global class LScheckforDefaultIntPayment implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime, State, CronJobDetailId
                          FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];

        Map<Id, List<Loan_Servicing__c>> tsid_lsListMap = new Map<Id, List<Loan_Servicing__c>>();
        List<Loan_Servicing__c> lsList = new List<Loan_Servicing__c>();

        LSClass.loadRTMap();         
        List<Loan_Servicing__c> lsListTemp = 
            [SELECT Id, Name, Term_Sheet__c, Status__c
             FROM Loan_Servicing__c 
             WHERE Amount__c > 0
             AND Status__c != 'Invalidated'
             AND Name LIKE 'TS -%'
             AND (RecordTypeId = :LSClass.rtMap.get(LSClass.INT_ACCR_UNPAID) OR
                  RecordTypeId = :LSClass.rtMap.get(LSClass.INT_ACCR))
             ORDER BY Term_Sheet__c];
        System.debug('LScheckforDefaultIntPayment() >> lsListTemp='+lsListTemp);
        ID ts_id = null;
        tsid_lsListMap.clear();
        for (Loan_Servicing__c ls : lsListTemp) {
            if (ts_id != ls.Term_Sheet__c) {
                if (ts_id != null) {
                    System.debug('ts_id='+ts_id+' lsList='+lsList);
                    tsid_lsListMap.put(ts_id, lsList);
                    System.debug(tsid_lsListMap.size()+' '+tsid_lsListMap);
                    lsList.clear();
                }
                ts_id = ls.Term_Sheet__c;
            }
            lsList.add(ls);
        }
        //      System.debug('LScheckforDefaultIntPayment() >>> tsid_lsListMap size='+tsid_lsListMap.size()+''+ tsid_lsListMap);
        //        LSClass.checkforDefaultIntPayment(tsid_lsListMap);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can build your map to use containsKey that will be easy. Please check my code.

```
global class LScheckforDefaultIntPayment implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime, State, CronJobDetailId
                          FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];

        Map<Id, List<Loan_Servicing__c>> tsid_lsListMap = new Map<Id, List<Loan_Servicing__c>>();
        List<Loan_Servicing__c> lsList = new List<Loan_Servicing__c>();

        LSClass.loadRTMap(); 

        List<Loan_Servicing__c> lsListTemp = 
            [SELECT Id, Name, Term_Sheet__c, Status__c
             FROM Loan_Servicing__c 
             WHERE Amount__c > 0
             AND Term_Sheet__c != null  //filter it in the SOQL
             AND Status__c != 'Invalidated'
             AND Name LIKE 'TS -%'
             AND (RecordTypeId = :LSClass.rtMap.get(LSClass.INT_ACCR_UNPAID) OR
                  RecordTypeId = :LSClass.rtMap.get(LSClass.INT_ACCR))
             ORDER BY Term_Sheet__c];

        for (Loan_Servicing__c ls : lsListTemp) {
            Id ts_id = ls.Term_Sheet__c;

            if (!tsid_lsListMap.containsKey(ts_id)) {
                tsid_lsListMap.put(ts_id, new List<Term_Sheet__c>());
            }
            tsid_lsListMap.get(ts_id).add(ls);
        }
        //      System.debug('LScheckforDefaultIntPayment() >>> tsid_lsListMap size='+tsid_lsListMap.size()+''+ tsid_lsListMap);
        //        LSClass.checkforDefaultIntPayment(tsid_lsListMap);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You are definitely right that it's much easier and cleaner to use containsKey to build the map. The concept solved my problem and thanks so much for your help!!